# Send 1 ERC20 TOKEN to anyone who execute the function

Tags: blockchain, erc-20, binance, binance-smart-chain

I have had this doubt for a long time.

I have a contract deployed that in the constructor mint 100 TOKENS (ERC20).

[image]

I have issues creatin a function in the smart contract WITHOUT Parameters that ANYONE can run it and the smart contract send to that person (msg.sender) that execute this function 1 of the TOKEN already minted.

Because i DONT need a function that i have to pass the address by parameter and without paremeters give me an error :(

Comment: we don't work for you! do some research, what you're asking for requires 1 minute of google search

Comment: Of course, i know that you dont work for me, i ask here because i dont found the answer nowhere. Help me :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really learn solidity, otherwise, you'll get stuck at every step

```
function claim() external {
    // require(totalSupply < the total supply required);
    _mint(msg.sender, 1 * (10**2));
}
```

this is an example of a function that you can add to your ERC20, if you want a limit to your supply you can add the `require`.
`10**2`, `2` here is your decimal, you can change it